# for loop isn't selecting the dates as I used the datewidget() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-animation, dart-html

Actually i am working on a github project which i downloaded it and practicing on it, but i am stuck in selecting the dates i used for loop to list the dates but when ever i click on it it isn't selecting those dates only the first date is selected already but other dates isn't selecting.

Leme show u the output:
here is the dates which i am trying to select but nothing happens also with the categories of learners and with the times too if u can help me with the dates i can understand the problem and fix the others too. Thank you!

[image]

Also forgive me for my bad english grammar.

here is the body part:

```dart
body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 260,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      left: 0,
                      top: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 200,
                        height: 240,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage('asset/images/iconBg.png'),
                                fit: BoxFit.contain)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      left: 20,
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: "boy2",
                        child: Container(
                          height: 220,
                          width: 200,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage('asset/images/boy2.png'))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Mr. Muneeb",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 21,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontFamily: 'product'),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "React Native",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: darkBlue,
                            fontFamily: 'circe'),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 20,
                            width: 20,
                            child: RotatedBox(
                              quarterTurns: 2,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.star,
                                color: darkBlue,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "4.9 Star Rating",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'circe'),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 20,
                            width: 20,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage(
                                        'asset/images/palette.png'))),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "5 Years Experience",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'circe'),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "About Muneeb",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 17,
                          fontFamily: 'product'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "I have been working on a React Native in a industry for almost 5 years working as a front-end developer, I can insure that i can teach you the best methods of working on a react native.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'circe',
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Courses by Muneeb",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 17,
                          fontFamily: 'product'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            courseWidget("icon1", "Young \nLearners",
                                "GRADE 0-1", lightBlue, darkBlue),
                            courseWidget("icon2", "Creative \nBloomers",
                                "GRADE 0-2", yellow, Color(0xff4d4d4d)),
                            courseWidget("icon3", "Early \nAchievers",
                                "GRADE 0-3", pink, Color(0xff4a155f))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Availability",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 17,
                          fontFamily: 'product'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) dateWidget(i),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              timeSlotWidget("11:00 AM", false),
                              timeSlotWidget("12:00 PM", false),
                              timeSlotWidget("01:00 PM", false),
                              timeSlotWidget("03:00 PM", true),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              timeSlotWidget("04:00 PM", false),
                              timeSlotWidget("06:00 PM", false),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Here is the datewidget:

```dart
InkWell dateWidget(int i) {
    DateTime tempDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: i));
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        height: 60,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.11,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          color: (selectedDate == tempDate.day)
              ? yellow
              : lightBlue.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                dayValue(tempDate.weekday),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
              ),
              Text(
                tempDate.day.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please share your dateWidget() code

Comment: kindly check i've updated.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of the little information provided;

I suggest using a ListView Builder instead of the row and for loop in the widget tree, it will achieve your goal more effectively.

for example:

```
//All the available dates for the person
List<DateTime> _dates = <DateTime>[];
//Where to store the selected date
late DateTime _selectedDate;

@override
void initState() {
 //set the date 
 _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
 super.initState();
}

ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal
        primary: false,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        controller: scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => dateWidget(_dates[index]),
        itemCount: _dates.length),
  )


  //Date Widget
  Widget dateWidget(DateTime date) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      _selectedDate = date;  
    });
  },
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: _selectedDate == date ? Colors.yellow :  Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      child: ,
      ),
    );
 }
```

I hope that gives you an idea of how to go about it.

Comment: actually i tried this method but it gives an error in intializing late keyword.
if u want full code i can share the file to u. u can check what will fix my problem, if that is okay!

Comment: @MinhajUrRehman initializing late error happens when you are try to use a variable that is not set yet. I have edited my answer to show how you can initialize the date in the initstate